# MongoDB on Ubuntu EC2 instance - Primary member of replica set cannot be accessed using java

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am using Ubuntu t1.micro EC2 instance and installed MongoDB-2.6.7 using the link: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

The problem what I am facing is that I cannot access the replica set Primary member.

```
 ServerAddress address0 = new ServerAddress("<public_ip1>", 27017); 
 ServerAddress address1 = new ServerAddress("<public_ip2>", 27018); 
 ServerAddress address2 = new ServerAddress("<public_ip3>", 27019);
```

I am getting **MongoTimeoutException**.

The issue here is: **When I don't use PRIMARY's server address and set ReadPreference to secondaryPreferred, I could read from the available SECONDARY.**

And I could **read (and even write to PRIMARY)**, when I used any of these server address as **individual connection**.

```
 MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("<public_ip1>", 27017);
```

Replica Set configuration has been given below:

```
 {
    "_id" : "replicaSet",
    "version" : 5,
    "members" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 0,
                    "host" : "ip-10-0-3-76:27017"  //**private_ip**
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "host" : "ip-10-0-2-19:27018"  //**private_ip**
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "host" : "ip-10-0-3-144:27019"   //**private_ip**
            }
    ]
```

}

No problem with security configs also. I have set ALL for inbound and outbound.

Could any one please help me out solving this problem.

The error is given below:

**Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out                             after 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches {serverSelectors=[ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=secondaryPreferred}, 
LatencyMinimizingServerSelector{acceptableLatencyDifference=15 ms}]}. Client view of cluster state is {type=ReplicaSet, servers=[{address=ip-10-0-2-19:27018, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception=
{com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-10-0-2-19}}, {address=ip-10-0-3-10:27019, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception=
{com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-10-0-3-10}}, {address=ip-10-0-3-76:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception=
{com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-10-0-3-76}}]
    at com.mongodb.BaseCluster.getServer(BaseCluster.java:82)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getServer(DBTCPConnector.java:656)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.access$500(DBTCPConnector.java:40)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort.getConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:505)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort.get(DBTCPConnector.java:448)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:284)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:269)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:84)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:320)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:299)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.getCount(DBCollection.java:1269)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.count(DBCursor.java:796)
    at com.test.replicaSetTest.main(replicaSetTest.java:41)**

Comment: Please include more details. What code are you using to connect to the replica set?

Comment: Not using any other code to connect.. 3 ServerAddress for 3 member replica set.. it wasn't connecting to Primary member.. but if I comment Primary's ServerAddress and used ReadPreference as secondary, then I could read from db.. But individual MongoClient to Primary was working.

Comment: You are not including all the code - you must, for example, be constructing a `MongoClient` from your 3 server addresses and setting the read preference. Have you tried connecting without setting the read preference or `acceptableLatencyDifference`? Can you include the full code?

Comment: Yes I tried without ReadPreference also. Primary did not connect (MongoTimeOutException). I used ReadPreference , just to check whether Secondary can be communicated (this worked fine, no problem). The doubt which I have got is whether the "host:port" in the replicaSet configuration itself to be used in MongoClient???? I used private_ip to configure replicaSet and public_ip in MongoClient. Is this the actual problem I'm facing???

Comment: Yes. The clients must be able to connect to the replica set members using the names in the replica set configuration.

Comment: How we can have same ips in the ReplicaSet configuration and MongoClient connection?? Do we have to go for Elastic IP in the production??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70645/discussion-between-user3805045-and-wdberkeley).

Comment: I got know from this link: http://blog.mongodirector.com/best-practices-for-deploying-mongodb-on-ec2/. We have two options configuring static ip address for ec2 instances (Elastic IP (this costs) and Route 53). Which would be the one which suits best for MongoDB production???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use Elastic IP address. Attach one Elastic IP to each of the Ec2 instance Network interfaces.
you can refer this link: http://blog.mongodirector.com/best-practices-for-deploying-mongodb-on-ec2/